# .htaccess issue instead of not found page home page displays

Tags: php, .htaccess, self-hosting

I have some issue in my `.htaccess` file. when I browse `index.php/something` it is displaying index page but should display not found page. I checked `.htaccess` file even tried to recreate but no success.

Comment: How can anybody possible help you with an issue in your `.htaccess` file when you don't show it?

Comment: Please provide your current `.htaccess` rules.

Comment: i removed htaccess file but it still displays index page